# TypeError: add_widget() missing 1 required positional argument: 'widget'

Tags: python, kivy

I was following a Kivy tutorial by Tech With Tim and ran into an error (TypeError: add_widget() missing 1 required positional argument: 'widget') which I have no idea how to resolve, here's the source code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        self.inside = GridLayout
        self.inside.cols = 2

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text='Name: '))        *<---- ERROR HERE*
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.name)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text='Last name: '))
        self.lastName = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.lastName)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text='Email: '))
        self.email = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.email)

        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        self.submit = Button(text='Click Me!', font_size=20)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `self.inside = GridLayout` to `self.inside = GridLayout()`

Comment: Thank you, didn't notice that

Comment: @MGPFE, please when someone answers your question correctly, mark his/her answer as the "[right answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png)".